# proper result using gremlin query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

In neo4j i created 2 nodes as CP and ANZ. I created two edges as Sell and Buy between then with tx_amount attribute of that edge as 100 and 200 respectively.

cp --> sell -> 100 -> ANZ

ANZ--> buy -> 200 -> CP

Now i want to fetch the seller,buyer,tx_amount. so, if I select CP as seller side. Then it should print as follows:

```
==> [seller:CP, tx_amount:100, buyer:ANZ]
==> [seller:ANZ, tx_amount:200, buyer:CP]
```

See in the above result first row return valid ouput and the buyer side of second row also correct.Only thing is seller side of second row is not ANZ, instaed it is CP. So, how to solve this.

current query with output as below :

gremlin> g.v(0).outE().inV.as('seller').bothE('Sell','Buy').as('tx_amount').inV.as('buyer').select{it.name}{it.amount}{it.name}.sort{it[2]}

```
        ==> [seller:CP, tx_amount:100, buyer:ANZ]
        ==> [seller:CP, tx_amount:200, buyer:CP]
```

Comment: unable to club seller and buyer name in one shot.:(

Comment: I would recommend you to add more context and describe your problem so that others can understand or else you'll get downvoted or the question gets closed.

Comment: I want to show both supplier and buyer for a particular selected node. See in my case buyer is changing because of bothE()...Any otherway is it posible like using loop or back(?) or ifelsethen condition or reverse concept.

like if(bothE('Sell')) {
               print [ supplier = left node , buyer = right node ]
       } else {
               print [ supplier = right node, buyer = left node ]
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by placing headCustomerName as root and then define a child_rel between headCustomer and childcustomer.

```
g.V.has("headCustomerName","ABC Corp.").inE('child_rel').outV().as('buyer').outE('Sell_To').as('tx_amount').inV().as('seller')  \
      .select{it.customerName}{it.amount}{it.customerName}  
==>[buyer:CP, tx_amount:100, seller:ANZ]
==>[buyer:CP, tx_amount:200, seller:SS Tech]
==>[buyer:SAK Corp., tx_amount:400, Supplier:AB Infotech]
...
```

and ,

```
g.V.has("headCustomerName","ABC Corp.").inE('child_rel').outV().as('seller').inE('Sell_To').as('tx_amount').outV().as('buyer')    \
      .select{it.customerName}{it.amount}{it.customerName}  
==>[seller:CP, tx_amount:1100, buyer:NEW Int]
==>[seller:CP, tx_amount:1300, buyer:Marry Gold]
==>[seller:SAK Corp., tx_amount:1006, buyer:LLI Corp.]
...
```

Thanks. :)